# Side slidebar in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to make side slidebar with angularjs but I got stuck. My code looks like this:

.html

```
<a class="button is-success newAlbumButton" ng-click="toggleSidebar()">New album</a>
<div class="list list-inset searchclass" >
  <div id="leftSlideBar" ng-show="$ctrl.sidebarOpen">
    <label>Choose name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="newAlbum" placeholder="album name"> 
    <a class="button is-info" >Save</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.js

```
vm.toggleSidebar = function(){
   vm.sidebarOpen = !vm.sidebarOpen;
};

vm.closeSidebar = function(){
    vm.sidebarOpen = false;
};
```

.css

```
#leftSlideBar{
    background-color: red;
    width: 337px;
    height: 20%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 37px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}
```

So when I click on the `New album` button I want it to slide open. Clicking on the `Save` button should close it. Now the sidebar is staying open all time. I want it to begin as closed. My buttons are not working at all. :/
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
ng-click="toggleSidebar()"
```

should be

```
ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSidebar()"
```

Comment: Ahhh yes it was. I didn't realized that it wasn't there. :) thanks!